# Heroku can't connect with Postgres DB/Knex/Express

Tags: postgresql, express, heroku, knex.js

I have an Express API deployed to Heroku, but when I attempt to run the migrations, it throws the following error:

> heroku run knex migrate:latest Running knex migrate:latest on ⬢
>   bookmarks-node-api... up, run.9925 (Free) Using environment:
>   production Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)

In my `knexfile.js`, I have:

```
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DATABASE_URL
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './database/migrations'
    }
  }
```

I also tried assigning the migrations directory to `tableName: 'knex_migrations'` which throws the error:

> heroku run knex migrate:latest Running knex migrate:latest on ⬢
>   bookmarks-node-api... up, run.7739 (Free) Using environment:
>   production Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   '/app/migrations'

Here is the config as set in Heroku:

```
-node-api git:(master) heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            10.7
Created:               2019-02-21 12:58 UTC
Data Size:             7.6 MB
Tables:                0
Rows:                  0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
```

I think the issue is that for some reason, it is looking at `localhost` for the database, as if the environment is being read as `development` though the trace shows `Using environment: production`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide an object as your `connection` you're providing individual parts of the connection information. Here, you're saying that the name your `database` is everything contained in `process.env.DATABASE_URL`:

```
connection: {
  database: process.env.DATABASE_URL
},
```

Any keys you don't provide values for fall back to defaults. An example is the `host` key, which defaults to the local machine.

But the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable contains *all* of the information that you need to connect (host, port, user, password, and database name) in a single string. [That whole value should be your `connection` setting](https://knexjs.org/#knexfile):

```
connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if the Postgres add-on is setup as described in [these docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres) since the `DATABASE_URL` is automatically set for you as stated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/438).

Comment: Heroku Postgres should have already set this variable. The user doesn't choose the credentials or host; those values should be retrieved _from_ the existing environment variable. OP, did you change the value of that environment variable?

Comment: I set up the postgres db as outlined in the heroku docs. I did not change the value of the variable assigned by heroku. Editing question to show the heroku pg:config